# Serializer for mongodb default Object id with difference field name in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I want to change objectId name from 'id' to 'user_id' at the time of parsing in response for django request. i am using django-rest-framework-mongoengine

My user serializer looks like this

```
class UserSerializer(DocumentSerializer):

    user_id = serializers.Field(source='id')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        depth = 2
        fields = ('user_id','name','address')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define the field as:

```
from rest_framework_mongoengine.serializers import DocumentSerializer
from rest_framework_mongoengine.fields import ObjectIdField
from my_app.documents import User

class UserSerializer(DocumentSerializer):

    user_id = ObjectIdField(source='id')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        depth = 2
        fields = ('user_id','name','address')
```

The difference is that you should use the django-rest-framework-mongoengine's [ObjectIdField](http://umutbozkurt.github.io/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/fields.html#objectidfield).